# Subsets of free groups contained in $2$-generated subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\rank{rank}$Let $F$ be a non-cyclic free group.

> For which finitely generated subgroups $H< F$ such that $H$ is not of finite index in a free factor of $F$ does there exist a two-generated proper subgroup $K=\langle x, y\rangle< F$ such that $H\leq K$?

I'd be happy with a proof that it holds for all such finite subsets (unlikely?), and satisfied by a single counter-example. But a nice description of all these subgroups $H$ would be ideal.

The restriction on $H$ not being of finite index in $F$ is clearly necessary, as if $H$ has finite index in $F$ and is contained in a two-generated subgroup $K=\langle x, y\rangle$ of $F$, then we necessarily have $K=F$ (by for example the Schreier index formula). [For a similar reason, if $F$ contained a maximal subgroup $M$ which is finitely generated and not two generated then this would yield a counter-example. However, maximal subgroups of $F$ are not finitely generated.]

More generally, finite index subgroups of free factors have been removed from the question as these can also give counter-examples. For example, if $F=F'\ast F''$ with $F'$ of rank at least $4$ and $H$ has index $2$ in $F'$, then $H$ is not contained in any two-generated subgroup $K$ of $F$ (as otherwise $F=\langle H, a, F''\rangle=\langle K, a, F''\rangle$ where $F'=H\cup Ha$, and so $F$ could be generated by $2+1+\rank(F'')<\rank(F')+\rank(F'')=\rank(F)$ elements).

Comment: Isn't it absurd to denote $\lneq$ proper containment and $<$ containment? The normal way is to denote $<$ proper containment and $\le$ containement.

Comment: @YCor All containments are proper; I've replaced the $\lneq$ with $<$ to make it uniform.

Comment: Let $x$ and $y$ be free generators. Is $\langle x, x^y\rangle$ properly contained in a proper rank-2 subgroup?

Comment: @SeanEberhard I'm sorry, there is a typo in the question - $H<K$ should have been $H\leq K$. (This also contradict my above claim that "All containments are proper"!) So for $H=\langle x, x^y\rangle$ I want to take $K=H$.

Comment: Then is $\langle x, x^y, x^{y^2}\rangle$ contained in a proper rank-$2$ subgroup? By considering Stallings graphs I think not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the subgroup $H=\langle a,b^2,ba^2b^{-1}\rangle$ of $F=\langle a,b\rangle$ provides a counterexample.

To see why, first note that $H$ has infinite index in $F$. Now consider the Stallings core graph $\Delta$ for $H$. Let $x,y,z$ denote the three vertices of $\Delta$. For any subgroup $K$ containing $H$, we get an induced map $\Delta\to\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the core graph for $K$. If this map is an embedding, then $H$ is a free factor of $K$, and in particular the rank of $K$ is at least 3.

On the other hand, if the map isn't an embedding, then some two of $x,y,z$ must get identified. We can therefore proceed by performing each of these three identifications and then folding. What I got when I performed this computation by hand is illustrated here:

[image: Identifying and folding]

Note that, in each case, I get a finite-sheeted covering space of the rose. Therefore, $K$ has finite index in $F$. In particular, if $K$ has rank 2, then $K$ must be $F$ itself, and the inclusion wasn't proper.

To study these subgroups more systematically, I suggest you look at Puder's paper "[Primitive words, free factors and measure preservation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3991)" and his other papers that refer to it. In particular, the above computation is an example of his algorithm for computing the *primitivity rank* of a subgroup.

[I just noticed that Sean Eberhard suggested another counterexample in comments. You can check it in exactly the same way.]

Answer (score 7):

Recall that $F_2$ is $\pi_1(\infty)$, where $\infty =S^1 \vee S^1$ is a bouquet of two circles. Let $H \le F_2$ be a subgroup. Then $H \cong \pi_1(\Gamma, v)$ for some covering space $\Gamma$ of $S^1\vee S^1$. Observe that $\Gamma$ is a graph (generally with multiple edges and self-loops). By orienting and colouring the two edges of $\infty$, we get a corresponding orientation and colouring of the edges of $\Gamma$. Sometimes $\Gamma$ is called a *Stallings graph* (usually all "infinite hanging trees" are omitted from the drawing). Pick a spanning tree $T$ in $\Gamma$ and let $E$ be the set of all edges not contained in $T$. Then $\Gamma$ is homotopically equivalent to a bouquet of $|E|$ circles, so $H \cong F_{|E|}$.

Now let $\{x,y\}$ be a free basis for $F_2$ and let $H$ be a subgroup such that $\langle x, x^y, x^{y^2} \rangle \le H < F_2$. Let $v_1$ be the basepoint of $\Gamma$. Take two steps along edges labelled by $y$ and let the corresponding vertices by $v_2$ and $v_3$. Since $x, x^y, x^{y^2} \in H$, there are $x$-loops based at each of $v_1, v_2, v_3$. Since $y \notin H$, $v_2 \ne v_1$. Now either $v_1 = v_3$ or $v_1 \ne v_3$, but either way we see that $\Gamma$ has at least $3$ edges not in a spanning tree so $H$ has rank at least $3$.

Comment: Thanks for this, I really appreciate it! I wanted to say that I've accepted the other answer simply because it has "further reading"; there is little to chose between them otherwise.